# Python: MS Excel change table to grid

Tags: python, excel

I have a file with just 3 columns where column1 is connected to column2 and the link between the two columns is value in column 3. something like

[Image1](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/oueiShEZph0zpEsmcWiqOsfGpN9GWfKla1U8V_KNmng1J14Jv-HUlwx5C30BTG7DL48L6X__qNs=w1831-h851)

Now, how do I transpose Col2 to a row and make a grid as well as fill the values in Col3 to look as below.

[Image2](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/tZ7NNPZDTFWbUTl7ZmyuAV5lzLhaJL2h5a2gldrmm8c5bMyt-J6YRhMWgsO-CFoMGWdxfZpt78Q=w1831-h851)

Comment: You want a pivot table, but what does this have to do with python?  Are you trying to do this in python?

Comment: Hello Brionius, Yes this needs to be done in python. This is the fist part of the program later we would be building upon this.

Answer (score 0):

Save your excel sheet as a csv file, then use the `pandas` library.

Roughly speaking you want to import the csv into a `pandas` `Dataframe` object, then use the [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tools.pivot.pivot_table.html) method with the appropriate arguments.